# Wordpress me solicita mi servidor usuario ftp y contraseña ftp para instalar plugins

Tags: wordpress, linux, plugin, servidor

tengo un problema puesto que yo tengo permisos para entrar a dos servidores remotos, pongamosle al primero "serv1" y al segundo "serv2",
en el "serv2" tengo el servidor web de una pagina wordpress, pero para poder acceder a este servidor necesito ingresar al "serv1" y luego a través de un tunel inverso (ssh -t) logro acceder al serv2. (Todo esto a traves del terminal en linux)

Lo que sucede es que cuando estoy en el cpanel del wordpress del serv2, al momento de instalar un plugins para realizar backups me solicita la direccion de servidor web, el usuario ftp y la contraseña ftp. 
y estos datos no los poseo.

Es decir si poseo la direccion ip del servidor pero cuando por ejemplo intento acceder por el navegador con "ftp://192.bla.bla.bla" no me carga. Realmente soy novato en servidores. Por favor alguien que me pueda ayudar.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes evitar que wordpress solicite usuario y contraseña ftp añadiendo la siguiente línea en el fichero wp-config.php:

```
define('FS_METHOD', 'direct');
```

De esta forma, puedes instalar el plugin directamente desde el panel de control del wordpress. Lógicamente, el servidor web debe tener permisos correctamente configurados.